# How to get total sum of hours for each day

Tags: php

I have a situation where I need to calculate the total of hours for each sets on each day. But I have stuck many days on it. I try to get output as below:

```
Day        Clock In  Clock Out  Total Hours(Hr)   Total Hours Per Day(Hr)
Monday     08:00     09:00      1.00                                     
           10:00     12:00      2.00          
           13:00     14:30      1.50              4.50
Tuesday    08:30     10:00      1.50
           15:00     17:50      2.83              4.33
Wednesday  08:00     17:00      9.00              9.00

                                     Total       17.83
```

I have tried to code and do some effort this far. Kindly help me guys. Will appreciate it so much.

```
for($days=0;$days<3;$days++) { //get how many days

$clocked_records_each_day = count($get_attendance_records); //get attendance                 clock sets

for($records=0; $records<$clocked_records_each_day; $records++) {
$total_hour_per_set = $clocked_records_each_day[$records]['total_hour'];
$total_hour_per_day = ??;
$total_hour_overall = ??;
//stuck until here
//get the output and display
}

}
```

Comment: Can you show what's inside `$get_attendance_records`?

Comment: How are you storing the table of information?

Comment: $get_attendance_records contains rows for each clock sets per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically:

```
/* Init grand total:  */
$total_hour_overall = 0;

for($days=0;$days<3;$days++) { //get how many days

    /* Init day subtotal at each for loop: */
    $total_hour_per_day = 0;

    $clocked_records_each_day = count($get_attendance_records); //get attendance                 clock sets

    for($records=0; $records<$clocked_records_each_day; $records++) {
        $total_hour_per_set = $clocked_records_each_day[$records]['total_hour'];

        /* Increment day subtotal and grand total: */
        $total_hour_per_day += $clocked_records_each_day[$records]['total_hour'];
        $total_hour_overall += $clocked_records_each_day[$records]['total_hour'];

        /* Echo set total inside records for:  */
        echo $total_hour_per_set;
    }

    /* Echo day subtotal inside days for:  */
    echo $total_hour_per_day;
}

/* Echo grand total outside for loop:  */
echo $total_hour_overall;
```

Comment: How do I display the result in table format? The problem is because  $total_hour_per_set is displayed inside $records's loop but $total_hour_per_day is displayed outside $records's loop. I want them in same the same table.

Comment: If you want this the best way is to rewrite the code and pre-process values. Otherwise you have do add a check at the end of `foreach` loop: if current record is the last, you don't print last `<td></td></tr>` and you print it when you print `$total_hour_per_day`

Comment: I understand what do you mean. Now is trying to write it into code. I hope I can get it correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it in two parts, first sum it all up, then display it.

```
for($records=0; $records<$clocked_records_each_day; $records++) {
  $total_hour_per_set = $clocked_records_each_day[$records]['total_hour'];
  $total_hour_per_day[$clocked_records_each_day[$records]['day'][] =  $total_hour_per_set
  $total_hour_overall+= $total_hour_per_set;
}
```

So now you have all the data you need.

And for each day you can display

```
for($records=0; $records<$clocked_records_each_day; $records++) {
  Display( $total_hour_per_set = $clocked_records_each_day[$records]['total_hour']);
  Display( array_sum( $total_hour_per_day[$clocked_records_each_day[$records]['day'] ) );
  Display( $total_hour_overall+= $total_hour_per_set );
}
```

This assumes that you have a Display( ... ) function.